# Number of positive integral solutions of $w.x.y.z=840$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Find the number of positive integral solutions of $w.x.y.z=840$

If it were $w.x.y.z=210=2.3.5.7$, I would have easily done this. $4$ distinct objects are divided into $4$ distinct groups with empty group allowed, is found by $4^4$, just like the total number of functions. Empty groups are actually filled with $1$s, which is also asked @[Integral solutions to $x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3 \cdot x_4 = 210$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121578/integral-solutions-to-x-1-cdot-x-2-cdot-x-3-cdot-x-4-210)

For the given problem,
$$
w.x.y.z=840=2^3.3^1.5^1.7^1
$$
First $3$ identical $2$s into 4 distint groups with empty groups allowed, ie., $r-1=4-1=3, n+r-1=3+4-1=6$$\implies {}^{n+r-1}C_{r-1}={}^{3+4-1}C_{4-1}={}^{6}C_{3}$

For each such cases, the remaining 3 distinct objects are divided into 4 groups, with empty groups allowed, $\implies 4^3$

$$
\text{number of +ve integral solutions}=4^3.{}^{6}C_{3}=4.4.4.\frac{6.5.4}{3.2}=64*20=1280
$$

Is it the right way to approach the problem and is it the right solution ?

Comment: Your answer is correct.  In general, let $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$ be distinct prime natural numbers.  Let $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k$ be positive integers.  The number of positive integer solutions $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_r)$ to $$\prod_{i=1}^rx_i=\prod_{j=1}^k p_j^{n_k}$$  is given by $$\prod_{j=1}^k\binom{n_k+r-1}{r-1}.$$  For a proof, this is just a consequence of the stars-and-bars method.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool       Are we assuming the primes to be distinct?

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Is this not what I have used ${}^{n+r-1}C_{r-1}$ for distributing 3 identical 2's into 4 bins, since identical bins are allowed, ie., ${}^{3+4-1}C_{4-1}={}^{6}C_{3}$ ?

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Could you please confirm that its the right way to approach such problems ?